# Accessing shell environment variables in catalyst web app using Apache/FastCGI

Tags: apache, environment-variables, fastcgi, catalyst

I have a catalyst web application on an Amazon EC2 Linux instance and its content is being served by Apache/FastCGI.
Whenever I start a new instance, I need to get the internal IP of the database server and assign it to an environment variable by running this command at startup:

```
export MYSQL_HOST=$(dig +short ec2-*-*-*-*.compute-1.amazonaws.com);
```

I have a perl module that should create the database connection after looking up the $MYSQL_HOST environment variable value.

My problem is fairly well documented in that FastCGI cannot directly access these shell environment variables.

I see that you can use PassEnv from Apache mod_env to access environment variables and that you can assign values to FastCGI environment variables using the Apache directive, FcgidInitialEnv (if I hard-code a value in here, I can retrieve it using my Perl module).

My Apache configuration skills are rather basic so I was wondering if someone could recommend a way to tie these together in order for my perl module to access $MYSQL_HOST.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it might help to use PSGI to connect Apache and Catalyst, instead of FCGI

Comment: It kinda depends where you set the environment variable.  IF you want the fcgi process to inherit from apache's environment, that's one challenge. Another option is to have the fcgi subprocess calculate the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to read environment variables, have a look at $c->engine->env:

```
use Data::Dumper;
sub debugEnv :Local
{
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    $c->res->headers->header("Content-type"=> 'text/plain');
    my $req = $c->req;
    $c->response->body('$c->engine->env is : '.Dumper($c->engine->env)
                      ."c->req is $req\n"
                     .'c->config is ' .Dumper($c->config)
                      ."\nENV is : ".Dumper(\%ENV))
}
```